# How to make a SPDT switch without a switch itself

Tags: mosfet, pcb, pcb-design, switches, circuit-design

So I would like a SPDT switch to use on my PCB, but I encounter two problems.

1. I need to be able to run 30A DC through the switch.
2. I do not want to take alot of space, (i found 15A switch, but using two takes WAYYY too much space)

Something I considered is using a  dip switch to control a power MOSFET for over 30A, however I realize that is only SPST not SPDT. Does anyone have suggestions?

This is a circuit on a Printed circuit board. My goal is to be able to Run 30 Amps from the board, through to either a current sensor or a relay (in series with the current sensor). Prety much I always want the circuit to be current sensed, however I don't want the circuit to always pass by the relay. I want to manually control if the current passes through the relay or directly to the current sensor.

Incase of confusion - I do not want to know how to control a relay. I want advice on building a circuit that switches between two different outputs, with one solo input (the 30A trace)

Comment: There are many many things that could work, please describe your entire problem, edit the question and get it reopened.

Comment: what about using a low power spdt switch to control two mosfets that supply the same voltage? the low power spdt switch will be much smaller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create 30A PCB SPDT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/509305/create-30a-pcb-spdt)

Answer (score -1):

So I don't know how much space is too much space but I would recommend checking on [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278) for a suitable mosfet and using a small switch to control the mosfets. Something like this prehaps.
[image]

Comment: I'd strongly recommend pulldown resistors on each of the gates; there's very little leakage current to discharge the gate once SW1 disconnects, so there is a strong possibility of make-before-break with this arrangement (i.e. OUT1 and OUT2 both being connected at the same time).